Switching back from nouveau to proprietary tested driver with unknown chipset
My external monitor wasn't connecting anymore to my laptop. I tried switching to the Nouveau driver from the regular proprietary and tested driver in Ubuntu 22.04. Bad idea. This caused my laptop to stop booting, giving the error 'unknown chipset'. From what I have gathered, Nouveau isn't compatible with the NVIDIA Geforce RTX 4050 in this newer machine. It doesn't get past this black screen with the error message, so there's no easy way to switch back through the GUI interface.
I accessed the recovery mode of my machine. I read that going into either dkpg or root could solve the issue. I don't know how to proceed, though. All I want is to switch back to the proprietary and tested driver. There's a bunch of documents on the machine that haven't been backed up, so reformatting the whole PC would really set me back. Anyone who can help me fix this?
